# WebSockets connection refused

Tags: python, django, nginx, websocket

I have a Django app, with a real-time chat using tornado, redis and WebSockets. Project is running on the ubuntu server. On my local server everything is working good, but doesn't work at all on production server. I get an error

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://mysite.com:8888/dialogs/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>   privatemessages.js:232
>
> close dialog ws

I have tried to change nginx configuration, settings.py, tried to open the 8888 port, but still no result.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be you are using WebSockets as a separate service, so try to add the Access-control-origins  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to change the port... May be this will help somebody.

Comment: what did you change your port to? 8000? im having same problem.